# dbRDA in R, how to with abundance data and missing values for environmental data

Tags: r, vegan, rda

Using R, I'm trying to do a dbRDA on a set of abundance data of 9 species (units cells/mL) over 10 sampling days and I have 8 environmental variables (different units and some missing values). I want a test to show how the environmental variables are influencing the variation between the abundances across the days.

Q: Is a dbRDA the right test? Or maybe a CCA?

Q: How do I know if I should sqrt.dist = TRUE?

Q: What is the difference between using dbrda, cca and capscale?

```
dismat <- vegdist(Abundance_data, method="bray", binary=FALSE, diag=FALSE, 
upper=FALSE, na.rm = FALSE)

vare.cap <- dbrda(dismat~ T + F + S + Chl + Ice + AirT + WD + WS, data=df, 
dist = "bray", scale = TRUE, sqrt.dist = TRUE, na.action = na.omit)

anova(vare.cap)
anova(vare.cap, by="margin")
anova(vare.cap, by="terms")
```

Q: What is the difference between margin and terms?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please edit your question down to a single question; do not ask multiple questions at once. Also, some of these questions seem more like statistics questions than programming questions; for statistics questions try searching on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The questions are not very technical, and it may be wrong to answer to you. However, here answers to the current state of four questions:

Q. dbRDA or CCA: This cannot be answered briefly without being opinionated. There really is no answer: some people prefer dbRDA, others CCA. It is about the metric (= what do you mean when you say that two sampling units are different from each other), and how this is measured. This is an issue with scientific schools and traditions, and you really should consult your coworkers and supervisor to find out how things are done in your environment. Explaining these differences takes much more space than is possible to have in this forum. BTW, neither dbRDA nor CCA is a test, although they can be used with permutation tests after the analysis.

Q. To use sqrt.dist or not: Again, this is an issue with scientific schools. The problem that sqrt.dist tries to solve is that distance-based methods can give tiny negative eigenvalues with popular ecological dissimilarity indices, and in many cases these can be used by taking the squareroot of dissimilarities. These negative eigenvalues don't worry me, and I don't bother to use sqrt.dist, but many people are really horrified with them. The problem with using sqrt.dist is that then you are no longer analysing the specified dissimilarities but their squareroots. Most often the effects of negative eigenvalues only appear in later axes that you are not interested in, and those couple of the first axes are insensitive (for instance, using argument `add` does not much influence these), and if that is the case, `sqrt.dist = TRUE` is useless. However, you should again check the local tradition (ask your friends and supervisors) and work accordingly.

Q. dbRDA, CCA or capscale. For CCA, see the first answer. For `capscale`: do not use it, but use `dbrda` which implements (I think) a better method. However, `dbrda` and `capscale` only differ in their treatment of negative eigenvalues, and if there are no negative eigenvalues, both give the same results, and you can use either.

Q. Margin vs. terms: this refers to testing individual constraining variables (or terms). When you test terms, the variables are tested sequentially or in the order they are in the model definition: (1) the effect of first variable alone, (2) the effect of second variable after having first variable, (n) the effect of n-th variable after having n-1 variables. The "margin" refers to marginal effects or the unique effect of each variable after having all n-1 other variables in the model. This is the same definition as in other standard **R** functions (for instance in ANOVA of linear models `lm`). The sequential tests are sound whereas marginal tests may be more easily understood. Sometimes marginal tests are more useful, but they can be misleading. The difference between strategies depends on the inter-dependences (collinearity) of your explanatory variables, and if your variables are independent (uncorrelated), the difference vanishes.

Comment: Thank you! I have negative eigenvalues and so dbrda and capscale result in the plots being mirror images of each other. Is there a way to determine which one is correct?

Q: In plotting, in the dbRDA I only get the sample days as points and the environmental variables as the vectors, but in the CCA I also get species as points. Is there a way to add this in the dbRDA? 

Final Q: The vectors explain the variation caused by the environmental variables on the sample days or the species?

Comment: 1. The direction of the axis is undefined and mirror == image. You can see the similarity of two solutions using `plot(procrustes(sol1, sol2))`. 2. You can add species scores to a `dbrda` ordination using function `sppscores` (from **vegan 2.5-0**). 3. The total variance is for your data with rows of data being the units. So the variance is estimated separately as each species as a  unit and rows (sample days) as observations. Distance-based methods make a twist here, but basically the same.